# It is possible to get the location of classified content in Watson Visual Recognition?

Tags: ibm-watson, node-red, visual-recognition

I'm testing IBM's Watson Visual Recognition using Node-RED, I've trained it to identify some elements in the image, but I wonder if it's possible to get the exact position of these elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time it is not possible to get a location for anything other than a face which you do using the detect_faces end point. However we recognize this is a valuable feature so please “stay tuned”

Update: This is now possible with the v4 "Custom Object Detection" API: 
 https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-getting-started-tutorial